# loading extermal html into a dynamic text field actionscript3

Tags: flash

I have a dynamic text field and want to load twitter updates into this in flash using actionscript 3

The dynamic text field is called: myUpdates

Here is the code i have been using but am getting compiler errors saying that String is a static type and instances cannot have members dynamically added to it. I can see what is wrong tho?

```
    var twitterURL:String ="http://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline/19291040.rss";
var twitterXML:URLRequest = new URLRequest(twitterURL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(twitterXML);
myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);

function xmlLoaded(evtObj:Event)
{
    var twitter:XML = new XML(myLoader.data);
    var TwitterTitle:String = twitter.child(0).description;
    var UserUrl:String = twitter.child(0).link;

    var myUpdates:String = "";

    for each (var nodo:XML in twitter..item)
    {
        myUpdates += ""+nodo.title+"
"+""+nodo.pubDate +"

";
    }

    //The Title App > "Twitter updates "
    titleApp.text = TwitterTitle;

    //Display the value of myUpdates into the text field
    myUpdates.htmlText = myUpdates;

    //Actions for Follow Me Button
    followMe_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btFollowMe_CLICK);

    function btFollowMe_CLICK(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(UserUrl);
        navigateToURL(targetURL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myUpdates.htmlText = myUpdates;
```

Here you grap the local string variable instead of getting the TextField. Simply change the name of the TextField or the local variable, and you should be fine.